# $-\sum_{i=1}^\infty{a \choose i} \left(-b\right)^i> ab$

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients

I need help to prove or disprove the following inequality.

I've tried with many values, and they agree, but I am not sure.

Thank you so much in advance!

$$-\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty{a \choose i} \left(-b\right)^i> ab,$$

where $b\in(-2/3,0)$ and $a\in(0,1)$.

I thought on the equilavent inequality $(-b)^a<ab$, but I cannot solve either.

Comment: By the binomial series, the left-hand side is $-((1-b)^a-1)=1-(1-b)^a$. So you like to prove $1-ab>(1-b)^a$ under the given conditions on $a$ and $b$. See the fourth case of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality

Comment: Your second inequality is false for $a=0,b=-1.$

Comment: @subrosar, thank you, I was interested in $b\in(-2/3,0)$ and $a\in(0,1)$

Comment: @subrosar I see what you mean but those values of $a$ and $b$ are not allowed though.

Comment: @Gary thank you really much

Comment: Or $$a>\frac{1-(1-b)^a}{b}.\tag 1$$ You might try to find the maximum of the right side of $(1)$ in terms of $a,$ for $b\in(-2/3,0),$ using calculus.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $b<0$ and $0<a<1$. By the mean value theorem
$$
\frac{{1 - (1 - b)^a }}{b} = \frac{{1 - (1 - b)^a }}{{0 - ( - b)}} = a(1 + \xi )^{a - 1}  = \frac{a}{{(1 + \xi )^{1 - a} }} < a,
$$
where $0 < \xi  <  - b$, which is equivalent to the inequality in question.

Answer (score 1):

As Gary pointed out, this is equivalent to showing $1-ab>(1-b)^a.$ Suppose $a\in (0,1)$. At $b=0,$ the two sides are both equal to $1$. Now suppose $b<0.$ We have
$$
\frac{d}{db}(1-b)^a=-a(1-b)^{a-1}>-a=\frac{d}{db}(1-ab),
$$
since $(1-b)^{a-1}<1$ and $-a$ is negative. Therefore for all $b<0$ we have $(1-b)^a<(1-ab).$